# "No Activity found" error

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

This is my main page code:

```
package com.example.splasher;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static String text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // hide statusbar of Android
    // could also be done later
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
        EditText field= (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
        field.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus){
                if (hasFocus)    ((EditText)v).selectAll();
            }
        });
        text=field.getText().toString();
        try{
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.splasher.View"));
            }
       catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
       }
      }
     });
}
}
```

This is the code of my called activity:

```
package com.example.splasher;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class View extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // hide statusbar of Android
        // could also be done later
    //  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    //          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.view);
    //  TextView textview=(TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1); 
    //  textview.setText(MainActivity.text);
        }}
```

And this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.splasher"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".View"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.splasher.View" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I can't work out why I get this error. Any ideas? Names are all the same and with same upper, lower case letters. They are all described in manifest as well.

Comment: can you please explain y are you providing intent filter in you View acitvity in manifest file

Comment: I used it in previous application and it worked, so I just did the same

Comment: see there is no need of the intent filter which you have applied in the View activity..Just keep one intent filter in your MainActivity

Comment: I suggest you to add code to log in catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){

Comment: Karan_Rana-it doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Views.class));` Views class with 's' !

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest, type the activity action in caps.

<    action android:name="COM.EXAMPLE.SPLASHER.VIEW" /     >

this is done for all activities except for the main activity

Comment: The Intent-Action can be in caps, in lowercase, a mix,etc. As long as you use the correct name when making the Intent, it will launch. All the [documentation recommends](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/action-element.html) is a unique name.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need of the intent filter which you have applied in the View activity..Just keep one intent filter in your MainActivity

Replace the start activity line code with following:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,View.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your `startActivity` call by `MainActivity.this.startActivity` in your MainActivity.
I think there is a scope trouble.

Comment: Next try : `MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,View.class));` ?

Comment: can you send me your project ?